# Android. Two exactly same buttons have different shadows

Tags: android, android-layout, button

In my application I have screen for user's profile. It has two buttons for changing photo and password. Here's code of both buttons

```
....

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivUserProfile"
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"/>

        <Button
            style="@style/AppTheme.RaisedButton"
            android:id="@+id/btnSwitchPhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.White"
            android:text="@string/change_avatar"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

....

<Button
    style="@style/AppTheme.RaisedButton"
    android:id="@+id/btnSwitchPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.White"
    android:text="@string/changePassword"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

These buttons are exactly the same (except text), one of them inside `LinearLayout` and they looks same on preview in Android Studio. But when I open this screen on device, I see that buttons have different shadows. Here's screenshot
[image: Bottom button has more big shadow at the bottom]

Is there any issues?

Answer (score 3):

This is correct.

Android has two types of shadows - an ambient light and an omnidirectional light. Both cause views to cast shadows. The first one is a light reflected from the environment, is pretty much everywhere and generates a static, simple, gray around each view.

The second one is more dynamic and causes shadows to change with view's position. The omnidirectional light source is positioned above the screen. Just like in the real world, if something is further from a light, its shadow is shifted more. It's hard to notice, but the button at the bottom has more shadow on its left side, than on its right side. That's because it's shifted to the left.

Answer (score 0):

use  android:elevation="10dp" for both the buttons and see if it helps

Comment: it doesn't help

Answer (score -1):

```
    Looks andoid:layout_width is set to match_parent in the first case and in the second it is wrap_content. If it is wrap_content, according to the text, the button size shrinks. 
Moreover first one is inside linearlayout and the second one is outside and whether is it in any layout like Relativelayout?
Attributes are different from each layout
May be you keep both under same linearlayout and give a try by modifying only the text alone.

Hope that helps!!!
```

Comment: I've tried put both bottoms inside same parent container (LinearLayout) and set width to match_parent for second button, but there is still same issue. I've also tried to use other views (CardView and TextView with custom background and elevation) instead of Button, but problem still here: the second view has shadow which is bigger than shadow of the first view

Comment: Text present in the button is bigger than first one. You try with first button text itself and if you do not get any shadow, that is the main cause.

Comment: I tried set same text to both buttons. It doesn't help